# dronekit install error: instructions are not working

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

I followed the instructions to install dronekit-python as described in the Getting Started page.
I ran the following command:

```
pip install dronekit
```

and I got a message:

> Cold notfind a version that satisfies the requirements dronekit (from
>   versions: 2.0.0b2 .... 2.0.0rc9)

I did as *scaredrone* has prescribed two days ago:

```
pip install dronekit=2.0.0rc4
```

and I got the exception:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2606, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2544, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2512, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'dronekit=2.0.0rc4', 'at', '=2.0.0rc4')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try to run

```
sudo pip install --pre dronekit
```

the `--pre` flag enables installation of pre-release software. 
Don't know why it hasn't been documented.

---

Answer from here: https://discuss.dronekit.io/t/pip-install-dronekit-fails-on-odroid-xu4-unless-pre-is-used/93